# Default gateway of the router is wrong - 404 not found

Tags: ip, router, gateway, modem

I connected my router to my PC through the ethernet cable. I run the command ipconfig in the cmd and the default gateway is 192.168.1.1 (ethernet adapter local area connection), but the browser says 404 not found:

[image]

The router is a linksys WAG54GS and long time ago I changed the default gateway to 192.168.1.2 in order to use two router, but it doesn't work (impossible to reach it).

When I run ipconfig, I turned off the other router (D-Link) to be sure that the only router connected is the linksys.

Comment: Hold the RESET button on the back, about 5 seconds, to get it back to factory settings. Then you should be able to get to it via your browser.

Comment: Hello @RetiredGeek I did it and the result is the same. It's very weird

Comment: @RetiredGeek now it works very well, maybe the browser's cache was the problem. Thank you very very much for your helpful suggestion